# Не отображается полигон на яндекс карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, карты

Почему-то не отображается полигон, ошибок нет, маршрут строится, в общем все работает, кроме отображения полигона **centerPolygon**, в чем может быть проблема?

```
let data = {
    "start": {
        "latitude": 47.2373283,
        "longitude": 39.71242759
    },
    "finish": {
        "latitude": 47.49700305,
        "longitude": 39.94160203
    },
    "billing": {
        "km": 5,
        "min": 2.5,
        "base": 50
    },
    "zones": [
        {
            "name": "Центр города",
            "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                39.6997833,
                47.2381611
              ],
              [
                39.7078514,
                47.219743
              ],
              [
                39.743042,
                47.2272625
              ],
              [
                39.7350597,
                47.2421236
              ],
              [
                39.6997833,
                47.2381611
              ]
            ]
          ],
            "coefficient": 1.2
        }
    ]
}

ymaps.ready(() => {
    let myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [data.start.latitude, data.start.longitude],
        zoom: 15
    });

    let centerPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon(data.zones[0].coordinates);

    centerPolygon.options.set('visible', true);

    myMap.geoObjects.add(centerPolygon);

    routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
        options: {
            showHeader: true,
            title: 'Расчёт стоимости поездки'
        }
    }),

    zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
        options: {
            size: 'small',
            float: 'none',
            position: {
                bottom: 145,
                right: 10
            }
        }
    });

    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        types: {auto: true}
    });

    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
        type: 'masstransit',
        fromEnabled: false,
        from: [data.start.latitude, data.start.longitude],
        toEnabled: false,
        to: [data.finish.latitude, data.finish.longitude]
    });

    myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);

    routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then( route => {

        route.model.setParams({results: 1}, true);

        route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', () => {

            let activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();

            if (activeRoute) {
                let distance = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance");
                let duration = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("duration");

                let cost = calcCost(Math.round(distance.value / 1000), Math.round(duration.value / 60));

                let balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        '<span>Расстояние: ' + distance.text + '.</span><br/>' +
                        '<span>Время: ' + duration.text + '.</span><br/>' +
                        '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость поездки: ' + cost + ' р.</span>');

                route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);

                activeRoute.balloon.open();
            }
        });

    });
}); 

let calcCost = (distance, duration) => {
    let baseKm = 2;
    let baseMin = 5;
    let cost = data.billing.base;

    if(distance > baseKm) cost += (distance - baseKm) * data.billing.km;

    if(duration > baseMin) cost += (duration - baseMin) * data.billing.min;

    return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок координат карты и её центра latlong, а полигона наоборот longlat.
Вот полигон и строится у вас в Азербайджане, недалеко от Ходжавенд/Мартуни.

Про переопределение порядка координат, если это необходимо, можно почитать в документации Яндекс: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/